# Prettyfaces issue when using with viewparam converter

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

i'm using jsf 2.1, prettyfaces 3.3.3 and hibernate jpa 3.6.7. i have country page and i'm trying to send comment with commandbutton.

country.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="country" value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry}" converter="countryConverter"
                     required="true" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <title>Country</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry.countryName}" />
            <br/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="Comment:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{countryBean2.comment}" />
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{countryBean2.sendComment}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

countryConverter:

```
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {
    public static EntityCountry country = new EntityCountry();

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");


    @Override
    public EntityCountry getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM EntityCountry c WHERE c.countryName = :countryName")
                .setParameter("countryName", value);
        country = (EntityCountry) query.getSingleResult();
        return country;
    }


    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        EntityCountry c = (EntityCountry) value;
        return c.getCountryName();
    }
```

pretty-config.xml:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
                                        http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="home"> 
        <pattern value="/" /> 
        <view-id value="/faces/index.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

    <url-mapping id="country">
        <pattern value="/country/#{country}" />
        <view-id value="/faces/country.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

converter configuration in faces-config.xml:

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>countryConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-for-class>test.EntityCountry</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>test.CountryConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

when i open localhost:8080/test/country/england page firstly, everything works well. but when i try to send comment via commandbutton, countryConverter's getAsObject method is calling again with wrong string parameter (such as "test.CountryBean@bd9eff") and entity can not be found.

when i use with default ugly url (such as localhost:8080/test/faces/country.xhtml?country=england) and try to send comment, countryConverter's getAsObject method is calling with true string parameter and i can send comment successfully. i think it is a prettyfaces bug but i want to use pretty urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have another managed bean that named with "country" and i have pattern value named with "country" in pretty-config.xml.

```
@Named("country")
@SessionScoped
public class CountryBean implements Serializable {
    .......
}
```

when i change @Named("country") value, it is working successfully.

Comment: So your `CountryBean` managed bean was being named by default as `countryBean` right?

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps try to register your converter gobally for the `EntityCountry` type. If you are using `faces-config.xml` for configuration, use something like this:

```
<converter>
  <converter-for-class>com.myapp.EntityCountry</converter-for-class>
  <converter-class>com.myapp.CountryConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

From the PrettyFaces documentation:

> Please note that PrettyFaces will automatically use the JSF converter
>   registered for the type of the referenced bean property to convert the
>   path parameter. This means that PrettyFaces supports all JSF standard
>   converters and converters that have been manually registered to be
>   used for a specific type using the converter-for-class element in the
>   faces-config.xml (or the forClass attribute of the @FacesConverter
>   annotation).

If this doesn't work, please open a topic on the OcpSoft support forums:

http://ocpsoft.org/support/

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: i edited and added my converter configuration in faces-config.xml to my question. same error occured again. i also have topic on ocpsoft:
http://ocpsoft.org/support/prettyfaces-users/pretty-urls-turns-ugly-when-i-click-commandbutton-without-immediate-attribute

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but in my tests everything works fine. Could you perhaps open a new thread on ocpsoft.org to discuss this issue?

Comment: did you try with entity objects ? when i create country class with simple java class, everything works fine. the problem is occuring with entity objects.

Comment: Yes, I tested with entities. But that shouldn't make any difference. For the converter it is just an object.

Comment: i opened new topic on ocpsoft: http://ocpsoft.org/support/prettyfaces-users/prettyfaces-issue-when-using-with-viewparam-converter
i want to see your tests and if it is possible, i want to send my test project to you. thank you.