# Prettyfaces and Converter not working

Tags: jsf-2, converters, prettyfaces

In my web application I have a converter which converts from String to java.util.LinkedHashMap (and vice versa). When I try to use Prettyfaces I'm getting 404 resource not found errors. Here's my setup :

First of all according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842275/prettyfaces-issue-when-using-with-viewparam-converter), I tried decorating the converter with

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = LinkedHashMap.class)
```

I also tried adding

```
<converter>
  <converter-for-class>java.util.LinkedHashMap</converter-for-class>
  <converter-class>util.UrlConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

to my faces-config,xml.

Now the relevant code of my pretty-config.xml is :

```
<url-mapping id="details">
<pattern value="/dataset/#{id}" />
<view-id value="/faces/details.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

The URL rewriting itself works so I end up at URL : http://server.com/appname/dataset//someID
IMPORTANT : 
Here's what I think might be the problem : All my ID's start with a "/" so after the part "/dataset" there are always two "/". If this is the reason for my problem how can I rewrite these slashes then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `/` character is really the cause of your problems. By default PrettyFaces uses the regular expression `[^/]+` to match path parameters. So the mapping won't match if your path parameters contains `/` characters.

You should use a custom regular expression for the path parameter like described here:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.pathparams.regex

This means that something like this should work:

```
<url-mapping id="details">
  <pattern value="/dataset/#{ /.+/ id }" />
  <view-id value="/faces/details.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Another option would be to replace the `/` character with something else in your converter.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I couldn't test your proposal yet, but I have a follow up question. When I manually type in the correct URL like this http://server.com/appname/dataset/someID (so without the double slash) I get a blank page. Shouldn't this work correctly ?

Comment: ok I tested it and it works but I have another problem. I'm using primefaces fileupload component ([see](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf)) and the method, I specified for the "fileUploadListener" attribute isn't triggered anymore as soon as I have the prettyfaces library in my classpath

Comment: That's a well known problem people often run into. I think you have to configure the PrimeFaces filter to also intercept forwarded requests or something like this. Have a look at the forums. There are some threads regarding this: http://ocpsoft.org/support/search.php?q=fileupload

Comment: yes thanks I already found out about this. There's something about my initial problem though. I decided to replace all "/" in my ID's by "%2F" and in my converter I change them back. Now I should only need the setup I posted above right? However when I call an URL like http://server.com/appname/dataset/%2FsomeID I end up at a blank page and my converter method isn't called...

Comment: Any logs on the console. That shouldn't happen unless there is some other problem with your app. You should post more details about your setup on the PrettyFaces forums. I think that's a better place to discuss this. And I'm also not sure if using %2F will work correctly, because it is the encoded form of /. So it is actually the same as a /. Try something different like -.